# Public computer needs to pkill chromium when xscreensaver blanks

Tags: chromium, xscreensaver

What I need is for Chromium to be closed any time xscreensaver blanks the screen (public terminal at a hotel, people are remarkably lax about their own personal security). Attached is a script I found in the manual pages of xscreensaver-command.

```
           #!/usr/bin/perl

           my $blanked = 0;
           open (IN, "xscreensaver-command -watch |");
           while (<IN>) {
               if (m/^(BLANK|LOCK)/) {
                   if (!$blanked) {
                       system "sound-off";
                       $blanked = 1;
                   }
               } elsif (m/^UNBLANK/) {
                   system "sound-on";
                   $blanked = 0;
               }
           }
```

What I don't know is how to modify it to kill chromium instead of muting/unmuting the speakers. Help?
[Edit: Waltinator helped me a great deal, but now there's another issue: I get an error, as detailed in the comment below Waltinator's answer.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `system sound-off`, `/usr/bin/pkill -9 chromium`. Instead of `system sound-on`, (on unblank), `/usr/bin/pkill -9 chromium`.

Yes, `kill` it twice, dead is dead,  and `pkill` failing is not The End of The World.

Comment: Waltinator: I need your help. I keep getting error:
`Can't locate object method "pkill" via package "chromium"`

Comment: You need to leave the `system` call in. The line should read: `system "pkill -9 chromium"`

Comment: Use the full path: `/usr/bin/pkill`

Comment: IT WERKS! PRAISE BE TO THE SILICON GODS!